# FIrebase app not initializing on Vue3-Ionic Project

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, vuejs3

I use Firebase on a lot of my projects, but I never used it with vue 3 before. For an Ionic Project, I am using Vue 3 with typescript. What I would do to initialize Firebase projects on Vue 2 is, on the *main.js* file, this:

```js
new Vue({
  router,
  created() {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  }}).$mount('#app')
```

On vue 3 - *main.ts* -, tried:

```js
const app = createApp(App, {
  created(){
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  }
})
```

But I get the message:

> Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()

It works if the `initializeApp()` is outside "app definition", in the *root* of the file. What could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are trying to invoke a Firebase method before Firebase is initialized. Can you please share the complete code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initiate Firebase at the start of your app before even Vue is created, ideally in a dedicated firebase.js script that manages Firebase within your app.

```js
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Undefined variable firebase.

Comment: you haven't imported or declared the variable. this is not a firebase issue but a general  code issue